# How to effectively keep a laptop cool while running a server?

Tags: hardware, hosting, server-administration

I just hosted a home Minecraft server on a spare laptop, and I'd like the server to be up 24/7. (I join and play from a different computer).

I had my friend join the server, then I went for lunch, but when I returned, the laptop was hot as a teapot. I quickly shut down server and the laptop entirely to prevent damage.

I chose the 'Best' power plan and deleted all other apps, but there was no change.

How can I stop this laptop from heating up so much?

Comment: See what component is mostly responsible and replace it. Make sure all vents are uncovered. Place your laptop in the basement.

Comment: Can you use [Open Hardware Monitor](https://openhardwaremonitor.org/) to show those temperatures?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is about general hardware usage and not a gaming related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition Gigazelle's [excellent suggestion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/369309/28182) of a laptop cooler:

- **Keep the lid up** - Heat travels upward, and the laptop screen being closed acts like a blanket, trapping it inside. Laptops are usually designed for low power activity, or to hibernate/spin down/pause tasks when the lid is closed - overriding this behaviour to keep the laptop active with the lid closed can cause temperatures to spike.
- **Turn the screen off** - Most laptops have a way of turning the display on or off via a function key combination
- **Place the laptop away from heat sources** - including out of direct sunlight.
- **Make sure it's well ventilated** - the laptop would ideally have enough space around it to vent hot air out.
- **Point a fan in it's direction** - this is mostly a stop-gap measure until you get a laptop cooling pad, but the extra airflow can definitely help.

Ideally, as Gigazelle also mentions, you should consider getting a proper desktop to run the server, as laptops are not designed for long-term intensive activity like hosting Minecraft.

Comment: Thanks so much for the edit and the answer, that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [Laptop cooler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laptop_cooler) or laptop cooling pad. It helps take the heat away from the laptop and dissipate it through fans.

Generally speaking, a laptop is not an ideal type of computer for a dedicated server. Rather than spending money on a laptop cooling pad, I would recommend spending a bit more for a desktop computer that can easily run a Minecraft dedicated server. Desktop components are almost always less expensive than similarly-performing laptop parts.